# How to disable google maps dragging

Tags: google-maps

How to disable the dragging in google maps in your website in order to freeze it like an image? I've just used basic `Iframe` code that gives me google maps.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can set `draggable: false` in the `setOptions()` method on your map object:

```
map.setOptions({draggable: false});
```

More [here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)(Ctrl + f and search 'draggable')

Comment: It doesn't disable moving the map using arrows, you also have to set keyboardShortcuts to false.

Comment: Note: This property is deprecated. To disable dragging on the map, you can use the gestureHandling property, and set it to "none".

Answer (score 7):

The `draggable` property has been deprecated.

To disable dragging on the map, you can now use the `gestureHandling` property, and set it to `"none"`.

You can also disable the use of arrow keys, by setting `keyboardShortcuts` to `false`

ex: `map.setOptions({gestureHandling: "none", keyboardShortcuts: false});`

Answer (score 3):

This CSS snippet will stop your maps being annoying. Users will no longer scroll over your maps and accidentally end up zooming. Maintain the map view with the display you've chosen by placing this CSS snippet in your Custom CSS area

```
.sqs-block-map {pointer-events: none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a static image of a map; use the [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)

Comment: You can easily generate a static map here: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html